# How to customize SQL query result (select in select)

Tags: sql, select, subquery

This might be very simple solution but I am struggling for hours without any results. Let me show my problem with example. I have a table:

```
productID|attributeID|attributeValue
001      | a01       | value1
001      | a02       | value2
002      | a01       | value2_1
002      | a02       | value2_2
```

I have tried to use this query code:

```
SELECT 
    productID, 
    attributeValue,
    NEW_attributeValue = (SELECT attributeValue 
                          FROM table1 
                          WHERE attributeID = 'a02')
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    attributeID = 'a01'
```

Above query code is only my conception. Code fail because there is multiple results from second sub-query. Do you have idea how to receive this result:

```
001 | value1   | value2
002 | value2_1 | value2_2
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is conditional aggregation

```
select productId,
       max(case when attributeID = 'a01' then attributeValue end) as a01,
       max(case when attributeID = 'a02' then attributeValue end) as a02
from t
group by productId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot table concept for column attributeID

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT u.productID, 
    u.attributeValue,
    NEW_attributeValue = (SELECT attributeValue FROM table1 WHERE productID = u.productID and attributeID = 'a02')

    FROM table1 AS u
    WHERE attributeID = 'a01'
```

But it's better to use conditional aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Using a PIVOT would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT productID, attributeID, attributeValue
            FROM table1
    ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT (
        MAX([attributeValue]) 
        FOR [attributeID] IN ([a01], [a02])
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

[SQL Fiddle Example Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91684c/3/0)